# From MySQL to XLS with DataNucleus (java)

Tags: java, mysql, excel, datanucleus

I'm trying to create a small app, to export MySQL data to .XLS.

The MySQL schema is from here: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-sample-database.aspx

Some sources:

**persistence.xml**
I'm trying to define a MySQL connection to a MySQL DB on my computer. And an xls file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd" version="1.0">
<persistence-unit name="JPA-SAMPLE" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">

  <class>com.example.poc.entities.Customer</class>
  <exclude-unlisted-classes/>
  <properties>
    <property name="datanucleus.ConnectionDriverName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="datanucleus.ConnectionURL" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/datanucleustest"/>
    <property name="datanucleus.ConnectionUserName" value="root"/>
    <property name="datanucleus.ConnectionPassword" value=""/>
    <property name="datanucleus.autoCreateSchema" value="true"/>
    <property name="datanucleus.validateTables" value="false"/>
    <property name="datanucleus.validateConstraints" value="false"/>
  </properties>

</persistence-unit>

<persistence-unit name="excel">
  <class>com.example.poc.entities.Customer</class>
  <exclude-unlisted-classes/>

  <properties>
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="excel:file:tutorial.xls"/>
    <property name="datanucleus.schema.autoCreateAll" value="true"/>
    <property name="datanucleus.schema.validateTables" value="false"/>
    <property name="datanucleus.schema.validateConstraints" value="false"/>
  </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

**Customer.java**
Here's my entity

```
package com.example.poc.entities;


import lombok.Data;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "CUSTOMERS")
public class Customer {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "customerNumber")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "customerName")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "contactLastName")
    private String contactLastName;

    @Column(name = "contactFirstName")
    private String contactFirstName;

    //...
    //and so on, all the attributes defined here

}
```

**Main.java**
One Main class, to start everything

```
package com.example.poc;

import com.example.poc.daos.CustomerDao;

import javax.persistence.*;

public class Main {

    private static EntityManager mysqlManager;
    private static EntityManager xlsManager;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EntityManagerFactory mysqlManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("JPA-SAMPLE");
        EntityManagerFactory xlsManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("excel");
        mysqlManager = mysqlManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
        xlsManager = xlsManagerFactory.createEntityManager();

        CustomerDao customerDao = new CustomerDao(mysqlManager, xlsManager);
        customerDao.exportAllCustomerToXls();
    }

}
```

**CustomerDao.java**
And I've a DAO class, to do the reading, writing stuff.

```
package com.example.poc.daos;

import com.example.poc.entities.Customer;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityTransaction;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class CustomerDao {

    private EntityManager mysqlManager;
    private EntityManager xlsManager;

    public CustomerDao(EntityManager mysql, EntityManager xls) {
        this.mysqlManager = mysql;
        this.xlsManager = xls;
    }

    public void exportAllCustomerToXls() {
        List<Customer> customers =
                mysqlManager.createQuery("SELECT c FROM Customer c", Customer.class).getResultList();

//        for(Customer c: customers){
//            System.out.println(c.getName());
//        }

        EntityTransaction tx = xlsManager.getTransaction();
        tx.begin();
        for(Customer c : customers){
            xlsManager.persist(c);
        }
        tx.commit();
    }
}
```

In the first case (see the commented section), I'm reading all the Customers from the DB, and write their name to the standard output. The program writes all their name suddessfully.

But, when I'm trying to write them to an xls file, I'll get the following error:

```
jan. 30, 2015 12:59:25 DU org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.query.ForwardQueryResult closingConnection
INFO: Reading in results for query "SELECT c FROM Customer c" since the connection used is closing/committing
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 14.187 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-01-30T12:59:26+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 37M/286M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.1:java (default-cli) on project datanucleus-poc: An exception occured while executing the Java class. null: InvocationTargetException: NullPointerException -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

But, when I'm creating one Customer object manually, and persist that, it runs successfully.

Can you show me some example, to persist some Objects to xls in Java?

Comment: and the log says? and those objects, have you detached them from the first datastore before trying to persist in the other?

Comment: @NeilStockton: There's no logging set up. I haven't detached them from anywhere. How can I detach them from a datastore?

Comment: how can you detach? read the docs of any JPA implementation ? close the EM. And if you have a problem then you SET UP LOGGING (because how else do you expect to debug?)

Comment: Okay, I'm not totally sure. If I close the `EntityManager` called `mysqlManager` after the line `List<Customer> customers = mysqlManager.createQuery(...)..getResultList();`, it still not OK. If I call `mysqlManager.detach(object)` for all the results, still not OK.

Comment: "still not ok"; my that tells people nothing. Look at the log.

Comment: Ok, I set up log4j. Here's the log of one execution: http://pastebin.com/tfMfMaG8 - I cannot see anything suspicious

Comment: No, that's a log of you enhancing the classes.

Comment: Okay. The app is executed by maven-exec plugin, and here's the log of the maven, and the execution: http://pastebin.com/Y8Ck6yub

Comment: No that's the log of Maven ffs, not your app at runtime

Comment: My app is started from Maven, there's the runtime log. There's no other logging, only theese two lines of error code: http://pastebin.com/1aNk1uTx ; If I catch the exception in the method `exportAllToXls()`, this is the stack trace: http://pastebin.com/RRuqy3Y5

Comment: There's no other logging BECAUSE you haven't configured it; see the docs for the software you chose to use. You should be using merge() when attaching DETACHED objects (assuming you have bothered to detach them - you can easily check them, and the LOG would tell you whether they are).

Comment: You also likely need to set the persistence property in the Excel datastore "datanucleus.attachSameDatastore" as "false"

Comment: Every log written to the stderr. EVERY LOG! Why am I any further, if I set up a logging enviroment?

Comment: The `datanucleus.attachSameDatastore` was the solution, thanks! Post it as an answer, and I'm gonna accept it as an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are attaching the objects to a different datastore you need to add the persistence property `datanucleus.attachSameDatastore` set to "false" to the EMF for Excel so it will check if each object already exists before deciding to add them